# Prove $\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)^{2}\geq (a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$

Tags: contest-math

> Prove that $$\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)^{2}\geq (a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$$ for $a,b,c>0$

Any hints/solutions?

Comment: Did you try expanding out the terms?

Comment: Yes. Would using AM-GM on the LHS help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding the terms, we want to show that

$$ \frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} + \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{c}{b} \geq 1 + 1 + 1 + \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} $$

This is true because

$ \frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{b}{a} \geq 3$ and $ \frac{a^2}{b^2} + 1 \geq 2 \frac{a}{b}$ by direct AM-GM.

Add up the cyclic versions of the above inequalities.

Comment: Also, it is equivalent to $$f\left(\frac ab\right)+f\left(\frac bc\right)+f\left(\frac ca\right)\geq 0,$$ where $$f(x)=x^2+\frac1x-x-1=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)^2}x$$